# Launch WebBrowser control and set it to Bing.com with search string

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have webbrowser control in Xaml. I need to launch it by setting it to http://bing.com and pass in some search keywords or criteria like Mp3 Converter so that when webBrowser display it, bing.com will have the search criteria in the box or show some results. This way, I dont have to type. any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(
    new Uri(
        "http://www.bing.com/search?q=Mp3+Converter",
        UriKind.Absolute));
```